# What does `du - hb` do?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, coreutils

With `du -bh` I think I get the apparent size in human readable format:

```
# du -bh
295K    ./test
```

However, I would expect the same from `du -hb`, but I get something else:

```
# du -hb
301926  ./test
```

I believe this is the same output as just `du -b` would give me.

```
# du --version
du (GNU coreutils) 7.4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the man page for `du`:

```
   -b, --bytes
          equivalent to '--apparent-size --block-size=1'
   -h, --human-readable
          print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

The `-h` switch will display the output using units, blocks have no units, so these 2 switches aren't suppose to be used together!

**NOTE:** The command `du` will therefore display its output based on which ever switch occurs last in the command line arguments.

#### Examples

*b switch examples*

```
$ du -hb XnConvert.x86_64.rpm 
13950768    XnConvert.x86_64.rpm

$ du -b XnConvert.x86_64.rpm 
13950768    XnConvert.x86_64.rpm

$ du -h -b XnConvert.x86_64.rpm 
13950768    XnConvert.x86_64.rpm
```

*h switch examples*

```
$ du -bh XnConvert.x86_64.rpm 
14M XnConvert.x86_64.rpm

$ du -h XnConvert.x86_64.rpm 
14M XnConvert.x86_64.rpm

$ du -b -h XnConvert.x86_64.rpm 
14M XnConvert.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Oooh, I see, I though I could use `-b` as a shorthand for `--apparent-size`.

Answer (score 4):

The `-b` (show in bytes) and `-h` (show in a human readable way) options are contradictory.

The last one is the one really used by `du`.